# Form Authentication Ticket null issue in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, autofac, form-authentication

what could the cause behind dropping of authentication cookie (.ASPXAUTH) intermittently in an MVC3 app?

I checked the size of cookie which seems to be around 2kB.

It flows without any issues during login and performing few actions in site. but after performing one specific action (where I am returning a pdf file from server and cookie in untouched there) it drops for a very few users.

Could there be any other reason behind user being logged out of system after certain action?

Comment: I just have got info that cookie can be dropped if your applcation is being recycled by the server. There are three conditions that would cause your application pool to be recycled by the server.

1. Over CPU usage.
2. Over memory usage.
3. No http calls for 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just have got info that cookie can be dropped if your applcation is being recycled by the server. There are three conditions that would cause your application pool to be recycled by the server. 1. Over CPU usage. 2. Over memory usage. 3. No http calls for 20 minutes.